# SonarQube on mac doesn't start after plugin

Tags: android, macos, plugins, sonarqube

After installing SonarQube 4.3.1 through Brew on Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks, when I navigate to localhost:9000, I could see the console but now after trying to install an Android plugin and restarting the server through terminal I can no longer view the localhost:9000 page? I even tried localhost:9000/setup but I only get page unavailable.

Could someone give an idea as to why the plugin would cause this behavior and how to fix this?

Thanks

edit:
I am using the latest version of the Android plugin that can only be installed via the SonarQube Dashboard. And as far as an error, as I mentioned when I navigate to the dashboard e.g. localhost:9000 it just gives me "Page unavailable" But if I uninstall from Home Brew and reinstall I can navigate there just fine.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information: which version of the Android plugin, what error do you get in the logs, ...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having an issue similar to this.  I found the log output in /usr/local/Cellar/sonar/4.5.1/libexec/logs/sonar.log.

My first issue was that I had run "sudo sonar start" so I was getting this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory is not writable: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar/4.5.1/libexec/temp...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission Denied
```

I fixed that by running "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/sonar/4.5.1/libexec/temp"

Then I was running into the issue that my hostname was not resolvable:

```
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to start database
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLExecption: IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: mymac.mydomain.com: mymac.mydomain.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"
```

I fixed that by adding "mymac.mydomain.com" to the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mymac.mydomain.com
```

Hopefully this helps you.  If not, maybe at least knowing where the logs are, you can troubleshoot.

Comment: adding my terminal host to the /etc/hosts was what did the trick for me, thanks could not find a solution anywhere else!